# Extending express-js in a ES-6 class: trouble binding getter and setter

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, binding, es6-class

It is of my interest to work with Express in a extended class. I want to define a getter and setter for a property, but doing so will not bind the methods to the instances. A workaround is to create a custom getter and setter method and binding it on the constructor, but it feels wrong.

```
const express = require("express");


export default class Application extends express {
    _endpoints;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this._endpoints = null;
    }
    get endpoints() {
        return this._endpoints;
    }

    set endpoints(paths: []) {
        this._endpoints = new Set(...paths);
    }
}


const myApp = new Application();
console.log(myApp) // ...express-app-object, _endpoints, and nothing related to the getter and setter defined.
console.log(myApp._endpoints) // null
console.log(myApp.endpoints) // undefined
```

Comment: How is it that you're using both `export` and `require()` in the same file?

Comment: I'm using ES2021.

Comment: Well, you have to decide if you're programming an ESM module or a CommonJS module - it's not going to work well to do 1/2 of each.  Use import with export in an ESM module and `require()` and `module.exports` in a CommonJS module with an occasional dynamic `import()` to load an ESM module into a CommonJS module.

Comment: I would not recommend using the code in the answer you've accepted for reasons I mention in a comment to that answer.  I have a recommended solution in my answer below.

Comment: Also, `require()` isn't part of ES2021.

Comment: Fair enough =:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It apparently has to do with the fact that `express` is not a class or a constructor, it's a factory function.  When you call `super()`, it calls `express()` and that creates a whole new object, that is not your object and does not have your prototype.  Referencing `myApp._endpoints` works because your constructor assigned that property in your constructor to the object that `express()` created, but that object does not have your prototype attached to it, it's a new object that Express created.

If you remove the `extends express` from your code and comment out the `super()`, you will see that it all works.

If you change express to any other actual defined `class` in Javascript, your `endpoints()` getter works just fine.

So, you can't extend express in this manner.

The express prototype is available and you can add things to it the way we used to before we had the `class` keyword.

---

I would not recommend using a `class` here at all because it implies to anyone reading your code that they can define methods for the class and expect them to work (which they do not).

Instead, just define your own factory function that calls the express factory function and then adds properties to the object it returns:

```
// factory function for my app
function Application() {

    const app = express();

    // add instance properties
    app._endpoints = null;

    // add getters/setters
    Object.defineProperty(app, "endpoints", {
        get: function () {
            return this._endpoints;
        },
        set: function (paths: any[]) {
            this._endpoints = new Set([...paths]);
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true,
    });
    return app;
}
```

This can be used either as:

```
app = Application();
```

or:

```
app = new Application();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
export class Application extends express {
    private _endpoints = null;

    constructor() {
        super();
        Object.defineProperty(this, "endpoints", {
            get: function () {
                return this._endpoints;
            },
            set: function (paths: any[]) {
                this._endpoints = new Set([...paths]);
            },
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
        });
    }
}
```

Usage would be normal:

```
const app = new Application();
console.log(app.endpoints) // null
app.endpoints = ['/auth/signin', '/auth/signout']
console.log(app.endpoints) // Set(2) { '/auth/signin', '/auth/signout' }
```

Comment: But, there's really no point in using a class at all here because you can't define class methods normally as my answer explains why.  I would not recommend this code at all as it will imply to anyone reading your code that they can then just define methods on the `Application` class and expect it to work (which it will not).  You may as well just define your own `Application` factory function that itself calls the `express()` factory function and then modifies its properties. Again, this structure is NOT recommended.